# How do I add Opacity to my eclipse container in flutter as shown below?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

With Opacity

[image: With Opacity]

Without Opacity

[image: Without Opacity]

I want to convert my container to opacity like shown above. How to do it?

Here is my code for the container:

```
Positioned(
  bottom: 0,
  child: Arc(
    arcType: ArcType.CONVEX,
    edge: Edge.TOP,
    height: 60.0,
    child: Opacity(
      opacity: 1,
      child: new Container(
        height: 140,
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.8),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: https://medium.com/fluttervn/how-to-make-blur-effect-in-flutter-using-backdropfilter-imagefilter-559ffd8ab73

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just wrap your Container with `BackdropFilter` widget so BackdropFilter widget takes one child and filter value. here u can get more info about [BackdropFilter Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html)

and if you wanna get wrapped your container with BackdropFilter widget you should be do this:

```dart
Positioned(
  bottom: 0,
  child: Arc(
    arcType: ArcType.CONVEX,
    edge: Edge.TOP,
    height: 60.0,
    child: BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3, sigmaY: 5),
    child: Container(
      height: 140,
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      color: Colors. black.withOpacity(0),
    ),
   ),
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

what you need is backdropfilter:

```
        Positioned(
          bottom: 0,
          child: Arc(
            arcType: ArcType.CONVEX,
            edge: Edge.TOP,
            height: 60.0,
            child: BackdropFilter(
    filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 5, sigmaY: 5),
              child: Container(
                height: 140,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                color: Colors. black.withOpacity(0),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the line

```
const Color(0xFF0E3311).withOpacity(0.5)

Container(
   decoration: new BoxDecoration(
     color: const Color(0xFF0E3311).withOpacity(0.5),
   ),
),
```

Comment: What he's looking for is a gaussian blur. If you're looking for a better performance opacity, simply use the Opacity Widget or .withAlpha instead of .withOpacity