# How to blur image in Container without blurring children Flutter?

Tags: image, flutter, dart, containers

I only want the image of container blurred (line:16). This is the code:

```
itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40, bottom: 20),
                        width: 250,
                        height: 450,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                              blurRadius: 8,
                              offset: Offset(0, 2),
                            ),
                          ],
                          image: DecorationImage(
                              image: AssetImage(
                                  Category_list[index]["background"]), //Blur this image
                              fit: BoxFit.cover),
                        ),
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                          children: [
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                              child: Text(
                                Category_list[index]["header"],
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 30,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.w800,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
                              child: Container(
                                width: 250,
                                height: 50,
                                //color: Colors.white,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius:
                                      BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                                ),
                                child: TextButton(
                                  onPressed: () => {},
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Chat",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  );
```

But to use BackdropFilter you have to use the child-property from the container but this would blur everything. Does anybody know how to only blur the image? Do I have to separate the image-widget from the rest? And if so how does it still cover the complete Stack?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66068569/14247462 Check this answer/post, I guess it would be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Stack()` widget to show your title or anything on top of your blurred image.

Small sample example

```
Container(
 height: 150,
  width:150,
    decoration: new BoxDecoration(
      color:Colors.black,
      image: new DecorationImage(
        image: new NetworkImage('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQKgi8mXs-MtRnwuZVUKo1BwTXnKIl--6qZPzWmT4k3BV1wlN-vMgV2BdICGGHlekwnkVk&usqp=CAU'),
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    ),
    child: Stack(
      children:[
        new BackdropFilter(
      filter: new ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 2.0, sigmaY: 2.0),
      child: new Container(
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.0)),
      ),
    ),
        Text("Dog Name",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22,),),
      ],
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I tried to do that but it didn't blur the image: https://pastebin.com/G6fpQvL1

Comment: Here, I check my code on dartpad and its working https://gist.github.com/ChiragKr04/abde38abce5f25fd1a26d221802ca9c9